# Metamask wont show up when I am calling approve function using Erc20 token

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, metamask

JS retrieve contract:

```
  const[stateToken1,setStateToken1]=useState({ storageValue: 0, web3: null, accounts: null, contract: null });
  const[stateToken2,setStateToken2]=useState({ storageValue: 0, web3: null, accounts: null, contract: null });

 const Token1Contract=new web3.eth.Contract(
           Token1.abi,
           "0xAF9864F9076639C4f8224A60C3767e23883dEA7B"
        );

    const Token2Contract=new web3.eth.Contract(
      Token2.abi,
      "0x83B407C6ce811CE02A150CC6F968d9B14Ec77F39"
   );
```

JS approve function:

```
const Approve=async()=>{
     const p= await stateToken1.contract.methods.approve("0xC6E8dBA4D9Ecf99cA44c9f1D8d8Dc1994db20f18","10000000000000000000").send({from:stateToken1.accounts[0] });
     const g=  await stateToken2.contract.methods.approve("0xC6E8dBA4D9Ecf99cA44c9f1D8d8Dc1994db20f18","10000000000000000000").send({from: stateTOKen2.accounts[0});
     console.log(p,g);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>Approve()}>Approve Tokens </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to have set the contract field in your

> stateToken1

and

> stateToken2

state objects to point to the "Token1Contract" and "Token2Contract" objects respectively.

If you looked into your console on clicking the button, you probably would have got an error like "Can not read properties of undefined"

What you should have in your Approve() function should be

```
const Approve=()=>async()=>{
 const p= await Token1Contract.methods.approve("0xC6E8dBA4D9Ecf99cA44c9f1D8d8Dc1994db20f18","10000000000000000000").send({from:stateToken1.accounts[0] });
 const g=  await Token2Contract.contract.methods.approve("0xC6E8dBA4D9Ecf99cA44c9f1D8d8Dc1994db20f18","10000000000000000000").send({from: stateToken2.accounts[0});
 console.log(p,g);
}
```

However, this would only work out if you have set the accounts field in the state objects as well.

It would be best to use a function within your useEffect to handle connection to your wallet accounts and initialization of contract objects and then set the state objects to point to them as below.

```
const handleStartUp = () => {
   let accounts_ = [...async function call to handle connection to wallets and return array of addresses];
   const token1Object = {storageValue: ..., web3: ..., accounts: accounts_, contract: Token1Contract};
   const token2Object = {storageValue: ..., web3: ..., accounts: accounts_, contract: Token2Contract};

   setStateToken1(token1Object);
   setStateToken2(token2Object);
}
```

This function can be called in your useEffect to set the state objects before trying to access the functions of their contract fields from your

> Approve

function.